# GeoIP-specifing nginx redirect for multiple servers

Tags: nginx, redirect, geoip

I need redirection based on country code I get from GeoIP (ngx_http_geoip2_module), but as I see, I can't use `map` because I need different conditions and destination URLs for different `server` directives (server names).

Is there any way to do redirection without if-conditions in this case?